# Innodb cluster - add instance error - the server is not configured properly

Tags: innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

I am trying to add instance to my innodb cluster. I turned off my firewall on both hosts (local vms).

This is the output of the `cluster.addInstance('root@innodb-2:3306');` command:

```
ERROR: Unable to start Group Replication for instance 'innodb-2:3306'.
The MySQL error_log contains the following messages:
  2021-10-15 19:13:31.922188 [System] [MY-013587] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Plugin 'group_replication' is starting.'
  2021-10-15 19:13:47.112664 [System] [MY-010597] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='<NULL>', master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
  2021-10-15 19:14:13.496929 [Error] [MY-011735] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to innodb-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
  2021-10-15 19:14:23.498488 [Error] [MY-011735] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to innodb-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
  2021-10-15 19:14:33.508595 [Error] [MY-011735] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to innodb-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
  2021-10-15 19:14:43.520173 [Error] [MY-011735] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] Error on opening a connection to innodb-1:33061 on local port: 33061.'
  2021-10-15 19:14:47.373813 [Error] [MY-011640] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Timeout on wait for view after joining group'
  2021-10-15 19:14:47.373884 [Error] [MY-011735] Plugin group_replication reported: '[GCS] The member is already leaving or joining a group.'
Cluster.addInstance: Group Replication failed to start: MySQL Error 3092 (HY000): innodb-2:3306: The server is not configured properly to be an active member of the group. Please see more details on error log. (RuntimeError)
```

I've done `dba.configureInstance('root@innodb-2:3306')` beforehand.

Comment: I'm also with the same problem and I can't solve it, I'm almost replaced by Galera Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

What version of MySQL and MySQL Shell are you using?

This seems like a connectivity issue, please ensure the allowlist is set if needed: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-securing.html#create-allowlist-servers